# Создать объект годный для обновления grid

Tags: c#, nosql

Прошу подсказать в какую сторону копать:

Есть форма на ней грид, показывает результаты запроса, все работает.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;//cmd - выполненный результат запроса

DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dbdataset);
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
sda.Update(dbdataset);
```

Может ли кто привести пример, как в Грид (заголовки и строки) сунуть данные из объекта/массива? Т.е. речь идет о выводе простых переменных, без подключения к какой либо БД/таблице.

Comment: Вы хотите просто добавить данные в таблицу, не добавляя их в саму базу? Данные ведь у вас берутся из базы?

Comment: Да, просто данные, и просто добавить в отображаемый грид. Кодом просто показал, как сейчас ( из бд в отображаемый грид )

Comment: [Вставка записей в БД](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms233812.aspx) - Копать в эту сторону (первый пример), но не сохранять данные в базе.